# asp mvc post not sending form data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to send my form data to my ASP MVC controller but the form collection is empty.  The variables in the action are bound properly.  This is my Razor form

```
    @foreach (var recipe in Model.RecipesInCategory) {
    <form name="input" action="mycontroller/myAction/@Model.Id1/@Model.Id2" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <table >
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="AddBtn" type="submit" value="Add"  />
            <select id="dayOfWeek" >
              <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
              <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
              <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
              <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
              <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
              <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
              <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  }
```

and here is my controller.  The two GUIDs are coming through properly, but the dow variable is always null.  In fact, the Form has no entries at all.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myAction(Guid Id1, Guid Id2)
{
    var dow = this.Request.Form["dayOfWeek"];
```

Note that i have many forms on this page created in a loop.  is that a problem?

Comment: BTW, you should use action parameters instead of `Request.Form`.

Comment: I'm coming from the WPF world and my HTML is very weak.  I feel the HTML helpers insulate me from the HTML too much at this point.  I want to learn what happens under the covers before I start using abstractions.

Comment: I'm not talking about HTML helpers; I'm talking about action parameters.  They're much simpler than manually reading `Request`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The browser will only POST data from form elements with `name=""` attributes.

Comment: so let me see if i'm clear - POST uses 'name', and CSS/JS use Id?

Comment: Exactly​​​​​​​​.  `name` does not need to be unique.  (in fact, for radio buttons, it should not be unique)

Comment: SOB, I hate missing things like this.  Thx!

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu: Only form elements (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`) are submitted.

Comment: I have used `asp-for` tag helper but doesn't work, The `name=""` works. Why?